# When did the Marketing-Cloud tag replace the ExactTarget tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

I tried to apply the exacttarget tag a few minutes ago to a new post and the tag wouldn't come up when I began typing it in. Instead, marketing-cloud appeared after I typed the complete tag it, indicating it was a synonym or had been remapped (merged?) with the marketing-cloud tag.

I understand that this may fit with Salesforce's latest terminology and marketing of their products, but I find this very inconvenient in terms of managing posts and applying the appropriate tags for our use. Are subject titles to be modified as well when editing posts? What's the expectation and logic behind the change?

I'll add that it would have been helpful to have seen an announcement of some kind posted here or elsewhere that this was happening. I don't know how users can be expected to use the marketing-cloud tag instead of exacttarget if we don't let them know that's what's expected of them.

Comment: I agree, what about pardot etc?.

Comment: According to Help, this required a vote by users who had reputation earned in exacttarget in order for it to happen. It's in my hide list since I have no knowledge, but I routinely edit them to add the tag and improve if I can. Perhaps those who voted for this, didn't understand it's impact and we need to roll it back?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the entire exacttarget brand is being re-branded as the salesforce marketing cloud. Even their website shows very few references to the old name ( http://www.exacttarget.com/ )

I'm not sure how this relates to the other products. We should  try to motivate users to be more specific and start creating more specific tags for the exact products or features from within the marketing cloud they are asking questions on.